# Relation between monoidal category and universal property of the tensor product?

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products, monoidal-categories

The product of a monoidal category is called the tensor product. But looking at the conditions for it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category), they seem very different from the [universal property of the tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property). Is there a relation between these two?

Comment: Multicategories provide a link between these notions. See for example Chapter 2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305049.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no connection, besides that the tensor product is an example of a monoidal product.  The symbol $\otimes$ is often borrowed from this specific example as a symbol for a general monoidal product, much as the symbol $+$ for addition of real numbers is borrowed as the symbol for the group operation in a general abelian group.